# NetworkManager/networking process disabling eth0 after user login

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, ethernet

I am running a 14.4LTS desktop.  When the system boots, the network is configured based on the `/etc/network/interfaces` settings.  I can ping or login to the box remotely via ssh.

When the local user logs in via the graphical interface, they have the eth0 network running for about 10-30 seconds (wired icon is initially visible), and then the system removes/disables the device and no networking is available and only an empty wifi icon is shown.  I have a usb wifi device that has been configured in the past but it is not connected to the computer.

If I open a term and run `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`, networking is enabled (static address) and the NetworkManager icon changes to the wired icon and notes that the `ifupdown` interface is connected.

Some relevant log messages:

```
<trimmed for space>
```

and my NetworkManager.conf file:

```
# This file is installed into /etc/NetworkManager, and is loaded by 
# NetworkManager by default.  To override, specify: '--config file' 
# during NM startup.  This can be done by appending to DAEMON_OPTS in 
# the file:
#
# /etc/default/NetworkManager
#

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

#no-auto-default=00:1a:a0:53:a2:3f,

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

and my interfaces file:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback


allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.166.21 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.166.99
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.166.99
```

The wired connection used to start on its own fine; I believe this only started when I temporarily had to add a wifi connection to the box while my wired network was down.  I have, before posting here, removed my wifi configuration and I still have the same issue with the wired connection "going away".

Something got screwed up.  Any thoughts?  I can't seem to connect this specific user-only problem with other similar issues on the web.  The network is just down for most people with similar problems, all or nothing.  For my system, it seems to be user specific.

**Additional content**

Following on from my comment/reply below, here is my updated interfaces file.  I also only added the hotplug option during my own problem solving phases because I thought it was a nice feature in case I had to swap out cables for whatever reason.  I have removed the line just to take some people's advice.  Didn't make a difference.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.166.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.166.99
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.166.99
```

**Additional content #2**

I just realized that although the network was running, after using the ifconfig command, and dns resolution was working none of my network apps would connect to the Internet.  This includes Skype, email (Thunderbird), web browsing and PIA.  I set managed back to true in NetworkManager and restarted it.  All my apps work now.  I think this happened to me when I tried this method on my own before coming here seeking help.  So, what could be happening now?  Before "fixing" NM as stated, I could ping my router and do a nslookup/dig from the command line without an issue.  Ugh.  Any thoughts?  This seems a bit...irregular.  This isn't my primary desktop so I hadn't actually tried any apps after the changes mentioned earlier.

These appear to be the relevant log messages for the interface from syslog when I reconfigured/restarted NM:

```
Jun 15 09:21:33 morpheus NetworkManager[1325]: message repeated 5 times: [ <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)]
Jun 15 17:55:52 morpheus NetworkManager[1325]:    Ifupdown: get unmanaged devices count: 1
Jun 15 17:56:04 morpheus NetworkManager[1325]: <info> caught signal 15, shutting down normally.
Jun 15 17:56:04 morpheus NetworkManager[1325]: <info> exiting (success)
Jun 15 17:56:04 morpheus ModemManager[1134]: <info>  Caught signal, shutting down...
Jun 15 17:56:04 morpheus ModemManager[1134]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
Jun 15 17:56:04 morpheus ModemManager[13743]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.0.0) starting...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> NetworkManager (version 0.9.8.8) is starting...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Read config file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> WEXT support is enabled
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: init!
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_system_hostname
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPluginIfupdown: guessed connection type (eth0) = 802-3-ethernet
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_connection_setting_from_if_block: name:eth0, type:802-3-ethernet, id:Ifupdown (eth0), uuid: 681b428f-beaf-8932-dce4-687ed5bae28e
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: addresses count: 1
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: adding eth0 to connections
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: adding iface eth0 to eni_ifaces
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: autoconnect
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPluginIfupdown: management mode: managed
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPluginIfupdown: locking wired connection setting
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: end _init.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2010 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (23482128) ... get_connections.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (23482128) connections count: 1
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: claim_connection: assertion 'nm_connection_get_path (NM_CONNECTION (connection)) == NULL' failed
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - US New York City ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - US New York City'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - New Zealand ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - New Zealand'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Denmark ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Denmark'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - US West ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - US West'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Switzerland ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Switzerland'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Norway ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Norway'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - US Midwest ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - US Midwest'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Germany ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Germany'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Japan ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Japan'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Romania ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Romania'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Netherlands ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Netherlands'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing Optus Mobile Internet (handsets) 1 ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'Optus Mobile Internet (handsets) 1'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - AU Melbourne ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - AU Melbourne'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Singapore ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Singapore'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - US California ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - US California'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Hong Kong ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Hong Kong'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Sweden ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Sweden'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - AU Sydney ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - AU Sydney'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Russia ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Russia'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - US Silicon Valley ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - US Silicon Valley'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Ireland ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Ireland'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - France ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - France'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - CA North York ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - CA North York'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - US Florida ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - US Florida'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - US Seattle ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - US Seattle'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Turkey ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Turkey'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Israel ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Israel'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - CA Toronto ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - CA Toronto'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Finland ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Finland'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - US Texas ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - US Texas'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Italy ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Italy'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Brazil ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Brazil'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - UK Southampton ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - UK Southampton'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - India ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - India'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - US East ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - US East'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - UK London ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - UK London'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile: parsing PIA - Mexico ...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    keyfile:     read connection 'PIA - Mexico'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; disabled by state file
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Networking is enabled by state file
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <warn> failed to allocate link cache: (-12) Object not found
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): carrier is ON
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): new Ethernet device (driver: 'tg3' ifindex: 2)
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): preparing device.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Ifupdown (eth0)'
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: (nm-device.c:3918):nm_device_activate: runtime check failed: (priv->state == NM_DEVICE_STATE_DISCONNECTED)
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> ip-config (reason 'none') [20 70 0]
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> urfkill disappeared from the bus
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus avahi-daemon[1181]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::21a:a0ff:fe53:a23f on eth0.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus avahi-daemon[1181]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::21a:a0ff:fe53:a23f.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus avahi-daemon[1181]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> ModemManager available in the bus
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Policy set 'Ifupdown (eth0)' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus dbus[1069]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Jun 15 17:56:05 morpheus dbus[1069]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun 15 17:56:06 morpheus whoopsie[1438]: online
Jun 15 17:56:06 morpheus ntpd[2566]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus avahi-daemon[1181]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::21a:a0ff:fe53:a23f.
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus avahi-daemon[1181]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus avahi-daemon[1181]: Registering new address record for fe80::21a:a0ff:fe53:a23f on eth0.*.
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) starting DHCPv6 as requested by IPv6 router...
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv6 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus ModemManager[13743]: <warn>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> dhclient started with pid 13866
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus dhclient: All rights reserved.
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus dhclient:
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv6 state changed nbi -> preinit6
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus dhclient: Bound to *:546
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus dhclient: Listening on Socket/eth0
Jun 15 17:56:07 morpheus dhclient: Sending on   Socket/eth0
Jun 15 17:56:08 morpheus dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 1080ms.
Jun 15 17:56:09 morpheus dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 2160ms.
Jun 15 17:56:10 morpheus htmlgend[2457]: <1465977370292> : Generated: 42 ms: 18 images, 14 template files
Jun 15 17:56:11 morpheus dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 4180ms.
Jun 15 17:56:15 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set disabled
Jun 15 17:56:16 morpheus dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 8720ms.
Jun 15 17:56:19 morpheus avahi-daemon[1181]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::21a:a0ff:fe53:a23f on eth0.
Jun 15 17:56:19 morpheus avahi-daemon[1181]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::21a:a0ff:fe53:a23f.
Jun 15 17:56:19 morpheus avahi-daemon[1181]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 15 17:56:20 morpheus ntpdate[13856]: sendto(golem.canonical.com): Cannot assign requested address
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpdate[13856]: adjust time server 202.147.104.60 offset 0.006096 sec
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpd[13957]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Thu Feb 11 18:30:40 UTC 2016 (1)
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpd[13958]: proto: precision = 0.101 usec
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpd[13958]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpd[13958]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpd[13958]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpd[13958]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpd[13958]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 192.168.166.21 UDP 123
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpd[13958]: peers refreshed
Jun 15 17:56:22 morpheus ntpd[13958]: Listening on routing socket on fd #20 for interface updates
Jun 15 17:56:24 morpheus dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 18110ms.
Jun 15 17:56:24 morpheus dhclient: send_packet6: Cannot assign requested address
Jun 15 17:56:24 morpheus dhclient: dhc6: send_packet6() sent -1 of 79 bytes
Jun 15 17:56:25 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Jun 15 17:56:25 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun 15 17:56:25 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Jun 15 17:56:26 morpheus ntpd[13958]: Listen normally on 4 tun0 10.145.1.6 UDP 123
Jun 15 17:56:26 morpheus ntpd[13958]: 91.189.89.199 interface 192.168.166.21 -> 10.145.1.6
Jun 15 17:56:26 morpheus ntpd[13958]: 27.124.125.250 interface 192.168.166.21 -> 10.145.1.6
Jun 15 17:56:26 morpheus ntpd[13958]: 27.124.125.251 interface 192.168.166.21 -> 10.145.1.6
Jun 15 17:56:26 morpheus ntpd[13958]: 27.124.125.252 interface 192.168.166.21 -> 10.145.1.6
Jun 15 17:56:26 morpheus ntpd[13958]: 54.252.129.186 interface 192.168.166.21 -> 10.145.1.6
Jun 15 17:56:26 morpheus ntpd[13958]: peers refreshed
Jun 15 17:56:26 morpheus ntpd[13958]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Jun 15 17:56:42 morpheus dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 35840ms.
Jun 15 17:56:42 morpheus dhclient: send_packet6: Cannot assign requested address
Jun 15 17:56:42 morpheus dhclient: dhc6: send_packet6() sent -1 of 79 bytes
Jun 15 17:56:52 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <warn> (eth0): DHCPv6 request timed out.
Jun 15 17:56:52 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 13866
Jun 15 17:56:52 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jun 15 17:56:52 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Jun 15 17:56:52 morpheus NetworkManager[13750]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
```

That odd timestamp at the beginning is associated with the same event even though it looks like it was taking place at a much different time of day.  Maybe I've found a bug (yippee)?

Comment: Why do you have `managed=true` in `NetworkManager.conf`? Without it, Network Manager will leave alone interfaces configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Why do you have allow-hotplug eth0 there? Are you using some kind of scripts or more than one eth cable that uses the group hotplug to start these interfaces? comment that line out and the one mentioned by muru since you want a static ip from the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Also remove the eth0 at the very first line of auto lo eth0....

Answer (score 0):

Try this configurations:
NetworkManager.conf file:

```
# This file is installed into /etc/NetworkManager, and is loaded by 
# NetworkManager by default.  To override, specify: '--config file' 
# during NM startup.  This can be done by appending to DAEMON_OPTS in 
# the file:
#
# /etc/default/NetworkManager
#

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

#no-auto-default=00:1a:a0:53:a2:3f,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

and my interfaces file:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback



auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.166.21 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.166.99
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.166.99
```

Comment: Ok,I took the interface out of NetworkManager management.  I was hoping to manage it through the GUI, similar to Windows.  This is a desktop that a less proficient user uses predominantly.  The doco I've read indicates that NM should be able to manage a pre-configured interface in a setup like I had, but I will concede just to move forward.  So, I corrected the error on the lo interface configuration in the interfaces file and changed managed to false in the NetworkManagers.conf file. I've rebooted the computer.  It boots, I login and the interface is configured **BUT** the interface isn't up.

Comment: I think I had tried doing it this way prior to posting on this site.  Posting here wasn't my first attempt.  Why doesn't the interface come up automatically?  "sudo ifconfig eth0 up" works, but I want this to happen automatically.  I'll post the current interfaces file in an edited version of my original question.

Comment: Also, thanks for assisting me.  I appreciate it.

Comment: The auto is an alias for allow-auto which is used by the init scripts during boot to decide which interfaces are started. You had syntax errors in your interfaces also your NetworkManager wanted to do something on the change train.... So it could have been a combination of those. Did it work with the config given?

Comment: ~ maybe you have some kind of script running during start up that deactivates your interfaces did you look into your syslog for any hints?

Comment: Syslog hasn't been too helpful.  I've posted the noise from NetManager running.  See Additional Content #2.  My problems get worse/stranger.

Comment: There are a few things - what I do notice is your network manager still tries to reconfigure your eth0 are you sure you actually used all the settings given? Also I saw there is a wifi which is also managed by the NetworkManager. Also it tries to get DHCPv6 ? I also saw that a openvpn tun0 is going over eth0 which might be the reason for the eth0 being down. You have quite a few configurations in the NetworkManager tried to reset it and start from scratch so you know when the issue appears?

Comment: Is there a particular way to reset all of NetworkManager, in terms of settings?  I have removed all of the vpn connections (placed there by the PIA installation I think).  I have disabled IPv6 as I am not using it at this time.  How would I deal with tun0?  I rebooted and the behaviours were the same.  This time, however, instead of using ifconfig to bring up the network I did "sudo service network-manager restart" and ifupdown worked.  Sigh.  This is starting to drive me crazy.  Nothing indicated in the logs.  Shows all the normal notes about starting up eth0 successfully.  A few seconds in..

Comment: it says carrier is offline and then removes eth0 and by the time the user logs in there is no network running (until I manually kick it in the guts as described above). Running out of body space to add any log information but there isn't any indication in syslog that another script or program is running at the time that eth0 is disabled.

Comment: if networkmanager restarting brought it back up it means you still have your networkmanager managing your interfaces. Try purging the `network-manager` package and try then rebooting. You can bring up the interfaces manually if it doesn't work with `ifup eth0`

Comment: Also did you copy the config files I posted 1 to 1 to your machine?

Comment: Yes, NetworkManager is managing the interface.  I switched back to this method because of the issue noted earlier: when I only relied on the interfaces file the Internet applications on the desktop would not connect/resolve hosts - browser, Skype, PIA, etc.  And, also noted earlier, the interfaces-only configuration left eth0 configured but DOWN upon boot/login.  eth0 still needed to be brought UP manually.  Another non-ideal outcome.